# urllib2.urlopen does not add a "/" to the last of url with chinese automatically

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

Examples:

url_1 = "http://yinwang.org/blog-cn/2013/04/21/ydiff-%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%84%E5%8C%96%E7%9A%84%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F%E6%AF%94%E8%BE%83/"

url_2 = "http://yinwang.org/blog-cn/2013/04/21/ydiff-%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%84%E5%8C%96%E7%9A%84%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F%E6%AF%94%E8%BE%83"

As you see, if I don't add a `/` to the last of the URL, when I use `urllib2.urlopen(url_2)` it returns 400 error because the effective URL should be `url_1`, if the URL doesn't include any Chinese, the `urllib2.urlopen` and `urllib.urlopen` will add a `/` automatically.

The question is the `urllib.urlopen` works well all of these situations, but `urllib2.urlopen` just works well when the URL without Chinese.

So I wonder that if it is a little bug to `urllib2.urlopen`, or is there another explaination to it?

Comment: The two links are two different things, they aren't representing the same resource.

Comment: I doubt that urllib will ever add a `/` automatically. The difference has to be on the server side. Some servers are configured to treat such URLs as equal and some are not.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes, you are right and I know it, what I doubt is the difference between URL with Chinese and URL without Chinese to `urllib2.urlopen`. I don't know whether I meant what I want to mean or not...

Comment: @zvone What you said is right, but maybe it is  not the truth here, if it is, then why `urllib.urlopen(url_2)` works well and `urllib2.urlopen(url_2)` returns `400 Error`...?

Comment: What's an example of an URL where `urllib` adds a slash?

Comment: @Koterpillar I made a mistake, I thought `urllib` did, it should be redirected(added a `/`)  by the `server`... am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually happens here is a couple of redirections initiated by the server, before the acual error:

1. Request: `http://yinwang.org/blog-cn/2013/04/21/ydiff-%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%84%E5%8C%96%E7%9A%84%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F%E6%AF%94%E8%BE%83`
2. Response: Redirect to `http://www.yinwang.org/blog-cn/2013/04/21/ydiff-%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%84%E5%8C%96%E7%9A%84%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F%E6%AF%94%E8%BE%83`
3. Request: `http://www.yinwang.org/blog-cn/2013/04/21/ydiff-%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%84%E5%8C%96%E7%9A%84%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F%E6%AF%94%E8%BE%83`
4. Response: Redirect to `http://www.yinwang.org/blog-cn/2013/04/21/ydiff-结构化的程序比较/` (actually `'http://www.yinwang.org/blog-cn/2013/04/21/ydiff-\xe7\xbb\x93\xe6\x9e\x84\xe5\x8c\x96\xe7\x9a\x84\xe7\xa8\x8b\xe5\xba\x8f\xe6\xaf\x94\xe8\xbe\x83/'`, to be precise)

AFAIK, that last redirect is invalid. The address should be plain ASCII (non-ascii characters should be encoded). The correct encoded address would be: `http://www.yinwang.org/blog-cn/2013/04/21/ydiff-%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%84%E5%8C%96%E7%9A%84%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F%E6%AF%94%E8%BE%83/`

Now, it seems that urllib is playing nice and doing the conversion itself, before requesting the final address, whereas urllib2 simply uses the address it receives.

You can see that if you try to open the final address manually:

**urllib**

```
>>> print urllib.urlopen('http://www.yinwang.org/blog-cn/2013/04/21/ydiff-\xe7\xbb\x93\xe6\x9e\x84\xe5\x8c\x96\xe7\x9a\x84\xe7\xa8\x8b\xe5\xba\x8f\xe6\xaf\x94\x
e8\xbe\x83/').geturl()
http://www.yinwang.org/blog-cn/2013/04/21/ydiff-%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%84%E5%8C%96%E7%9A%84%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F%E6%AF%94%E8%BE%83/
```

**urllib2**

```
>>> try:
...     urllib2.urlopen('http://www.yinwang.org/blog-cn/2013/04/21/ydiff-\xe7\xbb\x93\xe6\x9e\x84\xe5\x8c\x96\xe7\x9a\x84\xe7\xa8\x8b\xe5\xba\x8f\xe6\xaf\x94\xe8\xbe\x83/')
... except Exception as e:
...     print e.geturl()
...
http://www.yinwang.org/blog-cn/2013/04/21/ydiff-š╗ôŠ×äňîľšÜäšĘőň║ĆŠ»öŔżâ/
```

**Solution**

If it is your server, you should fix the problem there. Otherwise, I guess it should be possible to write a urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler which would encode the redirection URLs in urllib2.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that `urllib` is using HTTP 1.0 and `urllib2` HTTP 1.1.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah, I think you got the point, I tested it and I found that the problem here is, the `URL` which `urllib2.urlopen` really used is redirected by added a `/` and it is changed to a str ("http://www.yinwang.org/blog-cn/2013/04/21/ydiff-结构化的程序比较/") and it's encode by `UTF-8`, the truth is `urllib.urlopen` works well but `urllib2.urlopen` doesn't, so the solution which you advised is right, there is an another solution, use `eff_url = urllib.quote(e.geturl(), safe=":/")` then `urllib2.urlopen(eff_url)` will work. anyway, this is a`encode` problem...